# How to remove specefic rows from linq result

Tags: c#, linq

I have this Linq to Entity:

```
        var sitesGrpByClientAndFreq = from cfr in clientFullReview2                                           
                                       group cfr by new { cfr.inspectionFreqvency } into g
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           inspectionFreqvency = g.Key.inspectionFreqvency,
                                           siteCount = g.Select(x => x.siteId).ToArray().Distinct().Count(),
                                           normalSitesCount = g.Where(x => x.isNormal == true).Select(x=>x.isNormal).ToArray().Count(),
                                       }
```

From the above linq I get this result:

[image]

My question is How can I remove all rows where `inspectionFrequency = -1`?

Comment: why you're not using `where`, `where inspectionFreqvency  != -1` ? see this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509017.aspx#SimpleWhereClause

Comment: Thanks,I missed it!Now I realise that it was silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix and match the `let` keyword with `where`. It could be something like:

```
var sitesGrpByClientAndFreq =
  from cfr in clientFullReview2                                           
   group cfr by new { cfr.inspectionFreqvency } into g
   let inspectionFreqvency = g.Key.inspectionFreqvency
   where inspectionFreqvency != -1
   select new
   {
       inspectionFreqvency = inspectionFreqvency,
       siteCount = g.Select(x => x.siteId).ToArray().Distinct().Count(),
       normalSitesCount = g.Where(x => x.isNormal == true).Select(x=>x.isNormal).ToArray().Count(),
   }
```